# Jenkins + Tomcat deployment failed

Tags: jenkins, tomcat7

I have Jenkins running as service and it is located in C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins. 
I have changed Jenkins default workspace it is D:\jenkins_workspace. 
Tomcat located in C:\Program Files (x86)\tomcat7 and it running as service,
project war file located in C:\Program Files (x86)\tomcat7\webapps
Now I configure Jenkins following way : 
Post-build Actions -> Deploy war/ear to a container then mentioning WAR/EAR files path C:\Program Files (x86)\tomcat7\webapps\prj.war , but it throws exception: 
 
Expecting Ant GLOB pattern, but saw 'C:\Program Files (x86)\tomcat7\webapps\prj.war'.

Can you help what is wrong ?

Comment: Did you have a look to this post?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28260278/jenkins-deploy-plugin-failing

Comment: Yes, I had saw this. But that didn't solve the issue. thank you for response